# Bean injection issue with java-sproc-wrapper

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-mvc

I am trying to use [java-sproc-wrapper](https://github.com/zalando/java-sproc-wrapper/), but I am having a hard time injecting the datasource into the constructor.

here is the error message that I get.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'UserSProcService' defined in file [****/target/classes/com/zozor/user/sproc/UserSProcServiceImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [de.zalando.sprocwrapper.dsprovider.DataSourceProvider]: : No qualifying bean of type [de.zalando.sprocwrapper.dsprovider.DataSourceProvider] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [de.zalando.sprocwrapper.dsprovider.DataSourceProvider] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:746)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:193)
....
```

here is the .xml file

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

<import resource="database/spring-database.xml" />
<import resource="userInfo/spring-user-information.xml" />

<bean id="testDataSource1" destroy-method="close" class="com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPDataSource" lazy-init="true">
    <property name="driverClass" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5435/myaccounting" />
    <property name="username" value="postgres" />
    <property name="password" value="postgres" />
</bean>

<bean id="testDataSourceProvider" class="de.zalando.sprocwrapper.dsprovider.ArrayDataSourceProvider">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <ref bean="testDataSource1"/>
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

and here is the java file:

```
@Service("UserSProcService")
public class UserSProcServiceImpl extends AbstractSProcService<UserSProcService, DataSourceProvider>
implements UserSProcService {

    @Autowired
    protected UserSProcServiceImpl(
        @Qualifier("testDataSourceProvider") final ArrayDataSourceProvider dataSourceProvider) {
        super(dataSourceProvider, UserSProcService.class);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean registerUser(@SProcParam final UserInformation user) {
        return sproc.registerUser(user);
    }
}
```

I do not know what I am doing wrong here. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't see the place in your xml where you define annotation config, what makes me think that you have defined two contexes (possibly because of declarations in web.xml if it is a web app)

Comment: It is a webapp. I am quite new with spring and I am not sure to understand what the context is... Before I tried using this library it worked but now I does not :) here is a link to the code on github: https://github.com/paulfournel/haltandcatchfire/tree/testSProcWrapper

Comment: Actually the java files are here:https://github.com/paulfournel/haltandcatchfire/tree/testSProcWrapper/src/main/java/com/zozor/user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you create 2 contexts: first is mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml, and second with (spring-security, spring-database).xml

To solve that problem you should remove from web.xml `ContextLoaderListener` and `context-param` attributes, and place in  *mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml* import statements with *spring-security.xml*, *spring-database.xml*

```
<import resource="spring-database.xml" />
<import resource="spring-security.xml" />
```